# Sendgrid email subject is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, sendgrid-ruby

I'm working with Ruby on Rails and trying to send emails for my application via sendgrid. I'm using sendgrid-ruby version 6.6.2. Everthing working fine and all the personalizations are being added perfectly, so the email subject. But when email is received, subject is missing from the email. I tried using

`personalization.subject = 'Hello from your manager'`  to add subject in personalization.

I also tried adding subject in mail object like

`sendgrid_mail = SendGrid::Mail.new`

`sendgrid_mail.subject = 'Welcome from your manager`

Subject is there with sendgrid-mail object before its triggered. But missing when i receive the email.

Comment: Did you figure this out?. Got exact same problem, i've tried to contact support but they are unable to solve code issues. They refer me to use Stackoverflow or their confusing docs.

Comment: @damuz91 - If you still facing the issue please validate sendgrid template once. I found we were adding subject in dynamic_template_data. So added subject there and that worked for me. But could not add subject like personalization.subject or using sendgrid_mail object.